# Integrating application with Redmine using gem redmine_client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

I have VDS with [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/). Several days ago I have installed [Planning poker](https://github.com/itbeaver/redmine_planning_poker) on the same server. The Planning poker app works (the main page is accessible via web-browser), BUT when I try to log in (no matter which data is entered), I'm getting an error:

> uninitialized constant RedmineClient::Client

All required gems (including redmine_client as well) are installed. The config file for it (config/initializers/redmine.rb) contains next code:

```
RedmineClient::Base.configure do
  self.site = 'http://localhost:8080'
  self.user = 'user_name'
  self.password = 'secret_password'
  self.token = '1a05e2fde6986e5fd5213d962252515e78ca052f'
end
```

Can someone tell me where I must edit variables for getting out the error ([screenshot](http://s49.radikal.ru/i125/1501/76/be6d8c3bf068.png))? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is:

```
uninitialized constant RedmineClient::Client
```

The screenshot shows this coming from your user model. I'm not sure when the `Client` class was removed, but it's not currently in the RedmineClient repository referenced by your Planning Poker README.

Looks like the `token` method lives in the `Base` class now:

https://github.com/itbeaver/redmine_client/blob/master/lib/redmine_client/base.rb

Try referencing `RedmineClient::Base.token()` in your model.